# #1054 - Unknown column 'xxx' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to get result from mysql database. Here is my query

```
SET @rownum := 0;

SELECT rank,playerName FROM (
                SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank,numberOfDinner
                FROM players ORDER BY numberOfDinner DESC
                ) as result WHERE playerName='Arifa';
```

But while executing this query i got following error
[image]

My 'players' table has below colums:

```
id  
playerEmail     
playerName  
playerImage     
playerFacebook  
playerTwitter   
playerYouTube   
numberOfDinner
```

Comment: can you approve the answer if it worked for you??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of maintaining ranking of Users, you can give points to users based on your logic and maintain that points. And at the runtime give the ranking by querying the users and sorting them based on your logic( in this case number of uploads ).